# Angular Js read json data from Wordpress php file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, wordpress

I have sat behind this all day. I am building a plug in and i am including angular js.

So far all is well but i am not able to get a php file to read from database and pass values to angular js

file.php

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'workout';

$results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT title FROM $table_name ");

$arr=[];
$i=0;

foreach($results as $r)
{
$arr[$i]['title'] = $r->title;
$i++;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
//echo '[{"title":"Demo Title"},{"title":"Demo Title"},{"title":"Demo Title"}]';
```

The way i know my code works is that when i uncomment the last part of my code above the code works. so for some reason the json serialisation is not working properly, also the commented code is what both  `echo json_encode($arr);` and `echo json_encode($results);` return. Why is angularjs giving me nothing? What am I doing wrong here.

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('workoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(params.url)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.records = data;
        });
}]);
```

Table

```
echo '<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="workoutCtrl">';
echo '<table class="table">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr >';
echo '<th>Title</th>';
echo ' </tr>';
echo ' </thead>';
echo ' <tbody>';
echo '  <tr ng-repeat = "x in records">';
echo '    <td>{{x.title}}</td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo ' </tbody>';
echo ' </table>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Are you seeing a response in network of Chrome browser?

Comment: Open that url in browser ... do you see proper data? What does an error handler tell you? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for more clues

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have a wordpress instance in that php file

Comment: have you tried `die()` after `echo`, in wordpress one have to `die()` specially in `wp_ajax_hookname` hook.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set response header in php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: so why does it work with hard code data? This is good suggestion but isn't going to resolve problem

Comment: Because you are sending a stringified response when sending in plain text.

Comment: Please reverse the negative vote. Check out the related answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script